# React with Appwrite v1.4 : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, cors, vercel, appwrite

I have created my project with React (create react app) frontend and Appwrite(Baas) and hosted it on vercel.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/account' from origin 'https://letthechathappen.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Things I have tried:

1. Registered my project as platform on Appwrite dashboard.
2. Tried assigning hostname on Appwrite in multiple ways like.
   i) Default (*.netlify.app)
   ii) As the vercel gives domain, added that as hostname on Appwrite (w/o protocol)
   iii) Reverified Project ID and endpoint.

Still facing the issue.

Comment: Have you configured your server for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)? If not, you will have to.

Comment: Can you share any references? It would be really helpful.

Comment: A search for "CORS Vercel" directs me to https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS not working on vercel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099946/how-to-enable-cors-not-working-on-vercel)

Comment: Thanks! Configured the CORS on Vercel, it resolved the issue.