# CORS issue with serverless function on Vercel

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, cors, vercel

Ive removed my API endpoint for privacy purposes. When I enter the link along with some search params in my browser, it works and returns the correct data.
However when I call the endpoint in my frontend, I get the following error
`Access to fetch at '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import * as RecipeAPI from "./recipe-api";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "",
  })
); 

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server running on localhost:5000"));

app.get("/api/recipes/search", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query);

  const searchTerm = req.query.searchTerm as string;
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page as string);
  const results = await RecipeAPI.searchRecipes(searchTerm, page);

  // console.log("Response data:", results);
  return res.json(results);
});

export default app;
```

After setting up CORS headers in your `Express.js` backend, the `' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'` still occurs.
..............................................................

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS not working on vercel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099946/how-to-enable-cors-not-working-on-vercel)

Comment: An empty string is not a valid origin.