Socket.IO WebSocket connection and CORS issues on production with Vercel
I'm facing CORS issues with Socket.IO in my MERN stack app hosted on Vercel. The setup works perfectly in development on localhost, but in production, I receive the following errors:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://homie-connect.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=F16kc2WQHLv9m_h1AAAA' failed.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://homie-connect.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=PBd4yO2&sid=F16kc2WQHLv9m_h1AAAA' from origin 'https://homie-connect-app.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


Server Setup:
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  pingTimeout: 60000,
  cors: {
    origin: "*", // Should I specify the frontend URL here?
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
  },
});

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" })); // Should this be set explicitly as well?

Frontend Setup:
useEffect(() => {
  let socket;
  if (token) {
    socket = io(BASE_URL);
    console.log(socket);
    setSocket(socket);
  }
  return () => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  };
}, [token]);

What could be causing these errors?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76159384/15353979
